# Bash file error

Tags: .bash-profile

When I type "./" followed by a file name, how do I find out which program is executing it? ie. I have some scripts like "derp.sh" that will execute if I type "/bin/bash derp.sh" but fail if I write "./derp.sh" (they have a shebang).

I assume this is what's happening, as I've been attempting to "make" install some things, and have also come into errors like:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./version.sh: Permission denied
make: *** [libavutil/ffversion.h] Error 126
```

This could also be responsible for the bash mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell bash which interpreter to use by adding a [SheBang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the very first line in your script(s).

For example, if it is a bash script you add

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

where excatly you find the `bash` executable can be printed via

```
which bash
```

for python

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

same here; `which python2.7` will print you the path to the executable. If you want to run a python (2.7!) script.